# SWRevealViewController not opening slide menu

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealViewController for a slide out menu in one of my project. I have a scenario in which I have a View Controller not connected to the reveal view controller/front VC/RearVC . I am moving to this VC from one of my VC via presentViewController().

My destination VC i.e "myVC" is embedded in a nav.controller and it has a menu button which I want should perform the sliding menu action, but I always get an error in the following line

```
self.test.target = self.revealViewController()
self.test.action = Selector("revealToggle:")
self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())//fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

**Neither the menu button nor the swipe is working** for me.

**UPDATE**

I even have tried this stuff of code -

```
var navController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myNVC") as! UINavigationController
    var navController: UINavigationController = 
     self.revealViewController().frontViewController = navController//fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    self.revealViewController().setFrontViewPosition(.Left, animated: true)
```

I have attached a version of my work in a demo screenshot below where you can see in the bottom of the story board there is a ViewController embedded in a nav. controller. So now how can I show the rear_VC while swiping.

Please help !!

[image]

Comment: this error means in here no swlrevalviewcontroller is available

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  Ya as I have mentioned that it is not connected to reveal view controller/front VC/RearVC but I want to perform the slide out menu....please help?

Comment: in which are you facing the error

Comment: root controller is rootViewController print once you get any result

Comment: Ya the root controller is my destinationVC. No problem in that.

Comment: then check on here navController you get the name or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103185/discussion-between-kamala-dash-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Please help me in this case. How to make any View controller as front controller?

Comment: are you tried my answer is any one of the choice it is works or not

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik It didn't work but now you have also removed your answer. I have a VC which is embedded in a part Nav controller. Now I want to make this VC as front VC. And this VC or it's Nav VC don't have any connection with the RevealVC. Please help.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Please check my updated question and my attached screenshot. Please help as I am in deep trouble due to this.

Comment: can you send your project to my mail ID karthik.saral@gmail.com, I will check and reply uou

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have sent the demo. Please check that out.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Did you check the project that I have sent you??